# Cakephp 3 Action Crud\Action\DeleteAction does not implement a handler for HTTP verb _get

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This Project CakePHP 3 latest version build with crud and crud-view plugins.

Use technology =
php framework **cakephp 3.5** 
plugin **crud 5.2, crud-view 0.9.5**

1. Whenever I remove any record then don't work delete method.
2. Then I manually try to add in url '/delete/1' for remove record but still not working and thrown this plugin error.

code=

```
 $this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete',
                // 'Crud.Lookup',
            ], 'listeners' => [
                'CrudView.View',
                'Crud.Redirect',
                'Crud.RelatedModels',
            ]
        ]);
```

All of the other method working properly. this is the latest version configuration.

Comment: "Whenever I remove any record then don't work delete method." I'm having trouble parsing this sentence to figure out what you mean. Can you elaborate? Manually visiting the delete URL probably isn't working because the action function is only allowing POSTs, not GETs.

Comment: Yes, your are right @GregSchmidt delete action always perform by post not get but this is crud plugins problem. so, you manually add post link for delete action.

Comment: It's still really not clear exactly what the problem is. Please add specifics about what you are trying, what your expected result is, and what the actual result is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello sir, this is crud plugin problem. Error solved by @admad. Add post link.